# Verifications with capture on static method

Tags: java, jmockit

I'm not able to capture the parameter of a static method. The static method is called in the tested method and then called a second time in the verifications block but this time the parameter is null so I have a NullPointerException...

Here's my code :

```
@Tested
private Service testService;

@Test
public void test {

    // Tested method
    Deencapsulation.invoke(testService, "testMethod");

    // Verifications
    new Verifications() {
        NotificationsUtils utils;
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> map;
            NotificationsUtils.generateXML(anyString, map = withCapture());

            // NullPointerException is thrown here
            // because in generateXML method map is null and map.entrySet() is used.
        }
    };

}
```

How can I capture the map variable when generateXML is called ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your test never declared `NotificationsUtils` to be mocked.
The following complete example works, though:

```
static class Service {
    void testMethod() {
        Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        aMap.put("someKey", "someValue");

        NotificationsUtils.generateXML("test", aMap);
    }
}

static class NotificationsUtils {
    static void generateXML(String s, Map<String, Object> map) {}
}

@Tested Service testService;

@Test
public void test(@Mocked NotificationsUtils utils) {
    Deencapsulation.invoke(testService, "testMethod");

    new Verifications() {{
        Map<String, Object> map;
        NotificationsUtils.generateXML(anyString, map = withCapture());
        assertEquals("someValue", map.get("someKey"));
    }};
}
```